# Directory files are not copying to HDFS with command 'hadoop fs -put <my local path> <hdfs path>

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am copying pig processed file in local system to HDFS path(which is linked to HIVE table) by giving below command but it is not copying.

Step1: data is in my local path

```
[root@quickstart plantoutput]# ll
total 4

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1469 Dec  3 02:37 part-m-00000

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec  3 02:37 _SUCCESS

[root@quickstart plantoutput]# pwd

/home/cloudera/Desktop/dealer/plantoutput
```

Step2: after applying the command, it is like this

```
[root@quickstart plantoutput]# hadoop fs -put '/home/cloudera/Desktop/dealer/plantoutput' /tabplant

[root@quickstart plantoutput]# hadoop fs -ls /tabplant
```

Found 1 items

> drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2018-12-04 21:52
>   /tabplant/plantoutput

Actually in my target `hdfs` the path does not contain `part-m-00000` and `_SUCCESS`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ? Is it the quotes ?

Comment: Did u checked in this path `hadoop fs -ls /tabplant/plantoutput/`?

Comment: Dear Sathiyan, Yes I checked and part-m-00000 and _SUCCESS are there. but my requirement is to copy part-m-00000 and _SUCCESS to /tabplant not to /tabplant/plantoutput because my HIVE table is mapped to the location /tabplant in DHFS. correct me if I have done any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

@Sekhar,

To copy only the files present in `/home/cloudera/Desktop/dealer/plantoutput`

you should mention the absolute file path are you can use like below,

```
hadoop fs -put /home/cloudera/Desktop/dealer/plantoutput/* /tabplant
```

When you just mention the directory it will copy as directory in the name of its parent.

Comment: Dear Sathiya, I used * but no luck. Now I am getting '/home/cloudera/Desktop/dealer/plantoutput/*': No such file or directory

Comment: Dear Sathiya, Yes it is working. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: you are welcome :) you can still up vote and acceptm ;)

Comment: if this is solving your problem.